# SimpleSAMLphp setup and SP metadata

Tags: php, apache, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, service-provider

I'm new to SAML 2.0 as well as SimpleSAMLphp. I have couple questions regarding to setup and metadata configuration.

I act as a SP and I need to configure metadata that will be sent to my IdP. The IdP has some specific configuration requirements. How can I specify `mdattr:EntityAttributes` element in authsources? I need to define allowed authentication methods there.

The second question is regarding to SimpleSAMLphp deployment. Can I have my protected site content on domain example.com and SimpleSAMLphp running on subdomain sso.example.com in the same machine? Should I change the PHP.ini's cookie settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [SAML V2.0 Metadata Extensions for Login and Discovery User Interface](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-metadata-extensions-attributes). This probably describes what you're looking for.

These articles might be helpful, too:

- [Creating authentication sources](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authsource)
- [Implementing custom username/password authentication](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-customauth)
- [MultiAuth module](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/multiauth:multiauth)

Comment: I have seen the first link you provided to me, however, it's a documentation about configuring extensions to "metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php". Shouldn't I configure these to "config/authsources.php" as a service provider?